# Join cells with comma and space except when cell is Empty / Blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example:  `=i8&", "&i9&", "&i10 but don't add ", " for any Empty cells`.
Result if all (three) cells have data: `data, data, data`.

Not the result I want, but I am getting: `, , data` (when the two preceding cells are empty).

TRIM doesn't remove the `, ,`, nor does Find/Replace.

To join three columns I use:

```
=i8 & i9 & i10
```

To break them up with a comma and a space I use:

```
=i8 & ", " & i9 & ", " & i10
```

But when one of the cells is empty I don't want ", " before the information from a subsequent column nor ", , " when it is two empty cells.

I have tried to sort on the comma and the space but sometimes that search finds nothing. Besides, I don't want to replace 'comma space' when there IS data. I tried TRIM but that didn't help since it seemed to have no effect, even when it was just an effort to remove one empty space.

Unless someone has a reliable TRIM statement for this?

I would prefer to have a statement that skips empty cells and doesn't include the ", " (comma and space) where there isn't data.

Basically the idea is joining three telephone numbers: "Home Work Cell" into "(515) 555-1234 (H), 515 555-9876 (W), etc."

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

1. concatenate with a space
2. then TRIM()
3. then SUBSTITUTE

   =SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1 & " " & B1 & " " & C1)," ",", ")

[image]

Comment: That will cause a problem if any of the cells contain spaces.  I would suggest first replacing those internal spaces, perhaps with NBSP.  eg: `=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(160)) & " " &SUBSTITUTE( B1," ",CHAR(160)) & " " & SUBSTITUTE(C1," ",CHAR(160)))," ",", ")`